# How to covert varchar data from temp table and insert into actual table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with the following columns and data types.

Cost table data types:

**Cost - decimal(18.5)**

**LineNumber - int**

**Product - nchar**

**Quantity- float**

I am trying to insert data from a temp table called "Test" into the table above.All the data in this temp table is nchar.I have tried the code below.I receive an error saying "**Error converting data type varchar to numeric**"

```
INSERT INTO Cost 
(
   Cost, 
   LineNumber, 
   Product, 
   Quantity
)
SELECT 
    (convert(decimal,ts.c1)),
    (convert(int,ts.c2)),
    convert(nvarchar,ts.c3), 
    (convert(float ,ts.c4))
FROM #Test ts
```

**Also tried**

```
INSERT INTO Cost 
(
    Cost, 
    LineNumber, 
    Product, 
    Quantity
)
SELECT 
    cast(ts.c1 as decimal(18,5)), 
    cast(ts.c2 as int), 
    cast (ts.c3 as nvarchar), 
    cast(ts.c4 as float)
FROM #Test ts
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Show some of data in `#Test`. Probably it is in format that can't be converted to decimal, float or int.

Answer (score 0):

That message means that the char data in your table cannot be converted into a number--it probably has an alpha character in it.

Try this to see which rows are giving you trouble:

```
SELECT * FROM #Test
WHERE ISNUMERIC(c1) = 0
OR ISNUMERIC(c2) = 0
OR ISNUMERIC(c4) = 0
```